# Why do I get an error message that .replace is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, replace

I have this function:

```
function countLitreKgSums(cProductIds){
  var cLitreKgSums = new Array();
  var cWeek = 0;
  for(i=0;i<cProductIds.length;i++){
    var cLitreKgSum = 0;
    $("#plan_table td[class='week']").each(function(){
            cWeek = $(this).html();
            var cLitreKgValue = $("input[name*='plan_table_week" + cWeek + "_prod" + cProductIds[i] + "_']").val();
            if (cLitreKgValue == "") {
                cLitreKgValue = 0;
            }
            cLitreKgValue = cLitreKgValue.replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
            cLitreKgValue = parseFloat(cLitreKgValue);
            cLitreKgSum += cLitreKgValue;
       });
       cLitreKgSum = Math.round(cLitreKgSum * 100) / 100;
       cLitreKgSums[i] = cLitreKgSum;
  }
  return cLitreKgSums;
  //console.log(cLitreKgSums);
}
```

I get error message that .replace is not a function but in other functions it works as it should. What is the difference?

Comment: String(cLitreKgValue).replace

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`cLitreKgValue` might be a number at the point where you try to call `replace` on it, not a string.  In which case, the error is correct - numbers don't have a `replace` method.

Comment: ...and to *correct* it ('cause I'm thinking that anleon is looking for an answer to that as well), change `cLitreKgValue = 0;` to `cLitreKgValue = "0";`

Comment: String(cLitreKgValue).replace

Comment: .toString() in JavaScript is a proper way to work with numbers in stories like this.

Answer (score 15):

Change this:

```
cLitreKgValue.replace(/,/g, '.')
```

to

```
("" + cLitreKgValue).replace(/,/g, '.')
```

Comment: Better to change `cLitreKgValue = 0;` to `cLitreKgValue = "0";` I think...

Comment: @Nick Craver why better?

Comment: You're not appending a string for every element that *doesn't* need any work that way.  Though it's better yet to make an overall change, I added an answer showing this.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the function String()

i.e.; String(cLitreKgValue).replace ....

String function:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp

Answer (score 3):

While the other answers work (and are correct, numbers don't have [`.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), it's a [`String` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)), I think an overall structure change is better, like this:

```
$("#plan_table td[class='week']").each(function(){
    cWeek = $(this).html();
    var cLitreKgValue = $("input[name*='plan_table_week" + cWeek + "_prod" + cProductIds[i] + "_']").val();
    if (cLitreKgValue !== "") {
      cLitreKgValue = cLitreKgValue.replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
      cLitreKgSum += parseFloat(cLitreKgValue);
    }
});
```

There's no reason to do all that work when you know it's `0` and doesn't affect the result, so if `""` means `0` and `anything += 0` has no net effect, just skip it :)