# Javascript replace function "is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with the following code. I want to replace a string by another one, and generate an img code. However, I got an error message: `str.replace is not a function`. Any idea why?

```
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <input type="button" value="See Code" onclick="myFunction();">
    <input type="text" id="code" name="code">

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var str = parseInt(document.getElementById("text").value);
        var res = str.replace("ftpadress", "htmladress");
        var code = str.concat("<img src='",res,"' width='100%'>");
        document.getElementById("code").value = code;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: `str` is result of `parseInt`, so ,it's a `number`. [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a String method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get an error message that .replace is not a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141337/why-do-i-get-an-error-message-that-replace-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Why are you calling `parseInt()` on a value that might contain the string `"ftpadress"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @mrlew pointed out,
`str` is result of `parseInt` and therefore, it's a number. `replace()` is a `string method`, so it will not work on a `number`.

If I understood correctly, you would like to replace a string, retrieve a code and then generate an image tag with the new string and code.

I'd go with...

```js
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" value="See Code" onclick="myFunction();">
<input type="text" id="code" name="code">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    //changed
    var str = document.getElementById("text").value; //get text
    var res = str.replace("ftpadress", "htmladress"); //replace
    var code = parseInt(str).toString(); //get code and cast it back to a string
    document.getElementById("code").value = code; //insert code
    var withTag = code.concat("<img src='", res, "' width='100%'>"); //generate tag
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

parseInt returns an integer not a string so you can not use str.replace() , you need to cast it first

just add str = str.toString(); before using the replace function

Comment: I doubt very much that OP will find `"ftpaddress"` in a re-stringified integer. Something's fishy.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the casting (parseInt function) and everything should work fine.

```
 <input type="text" id="text">
    <input type="button" value="See Code" onclick="myFunction();">
    <input type="text" id="code" name="code">

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        //changed
        var str = document.getElementById("text").value;
        console.log(str);
        var res = str.replace("ftpadress", "htmladress");
        var code = str.concat("<img src='",res,"' width='100%'>");
        document.getElementById("code").value = code;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't realize parseInt had this effect.