# Google Sheets script – replace blank spaces

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've got a script that's doing some onEdit formatting on a sheet of mine. All the rest is working well, and I wanted to include a line that deletes spaces from number values I'm importing. That last line is not working.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var cell = e.range;
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();  
  if(sh.getName() === "Trading Journal") {
    cell.setBackground('#fff');
    cell.setFontSize(10)
    cell.setFontFamily()
    cell.replace(/\s/g, "") 
}
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rkjO-ITeLdIHq-LLHfHcp6-1j1R0-giS6HGbwYdJ5Ek/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Did a bit of research regarding this, and it seems that `.replace()` is a string method and therefore may not work with numbers. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102953/javascript-replace-function-is-not-a-function/42103352)

But if you only need to remove whitespaces from numbers, here is a simple solution:

```
function rSpaces() {
    var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
    cell.trimWhitespace();
}
```

You can assign this on an onEdit trigger and check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) for any font modifications you want to add.

Comment: Trimming white space won't work – the blank spaces are in the middle of the numbers, i.e. 1 614.29